# Twitter Bootstrap - Make "scrollspy" trigger a bit sooner

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Twitter Bootstrap 3.2.0` and the nifty `scrollspy` feature in it. It works fine for me. I just have a long menu on the right side, and it is set to be `affixed`, and it corresponds to a huge amount of text. This functions without an issue with the following code;

## Questions

1. Without `data-offset-top="60"`, it doesn't 'stay put' right. I don't understand why this is.
2. I would like to make it 'trigger' sooner. Right now, a `<div>` with the corresponding `id` has to be almost all the way to the top of the page for the matching menu item to get *'highlighted'*. Is it possible to make this a bit quicker, maybe where it will trigger when it is around `200px` from the top?

## HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <!-- all of my page contents here, with appropriate "id" set on each to correspond -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" data-offset-top="60" data-spy="affix" data-theme-role="sidebar" id="sidebar-menu">
        <ul class="nav sidenav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#alpha">alpha</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#alpha_1">alpha[1]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#beta">beta</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#gamma">gamma</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#gamma_1">gamma[1]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#gamma_2">gamma[2]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#gamma_3">gamma[3]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#delta">delta</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#delta_1">delta[1]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#delta_2">delta[2]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#epsilon">epsilon</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#epsilon_1">epsilon[1]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#epsilon_2">epsilon[2]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#zeta">zeta</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#zeta_1">zeta[1]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#zeta_2">zeta[2]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#eta">eta</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#eta_1">eta[1]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#eta_2">eta[2]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#theta">theta</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#theta_1">theta[1]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#theta_2">theta[2]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues,

1- The data-offset-top kind of tells the affix plugin when to get started....so how far down the user scrolls until it needs to affix the div you have set up. 
something that might work better than just a hard coded number, 60, is to set up the affix in javascript, rather than the attributes of the HTML element. and when you set the offset, you can get the exact starting position of the element, and then have the affix only kick in after that location has been scrolled past.

```
$('#sidebar-menu').affix({ //this sets up the affix plugin
    offset: $('#sidebar-menu').position().top //this gets the exact 
           //location of the div and only starts to affix after that
});
```

when you use the javascript method, you should take out the

```
data-offset-top="60" data-spy="affix"
```

2- The data offset should work, again, maybe try the javascript version

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').scrollspy({ 
        target: '#sidesummary',
        offset: 100
    });
});
```